# Can Entity Framework Auto-Update Property Navigation By Id

Tags: c#, entity-framework

In Entity Framework, when I've mapped my tables to the corresponding entities through the designer and get to actually using them, I'll find that an entity - `Thing`, who has a relationship (many to one, or one to one) with another object, say, `Bob`, for example, would produce the following three properties on `Thing`:

```
Bob
BobId
BobReference
```

And were I to set `BobId`, and save my entity, the next time I fetch this `Thing`, I'll be able to navigate the `Bob` property without trouble. I'm curious, however, if it is possible to configure EF to allow me to navigate the property without having to immediately save.

Comment: Have you disabled lazy loading?  If lazy loading is enabled, you shouldn't have to explicitly load the navigation property.

Comment: This isn't due to lazy loading being enabled or not. It is in fact enabled anyway; the question was if, after setting the ID of a relation on a model's property, there was any way to have the property itself auto-load upon navigation.

Comment: If I am understanding the scenario correctly, I believe lazy loading would do it.  From what I have seen of its behavior, if you attempt to access a navigation property, and the property is null, it always attempts to load the property, and in this case it would use the FK value that you just updated, even if you have not yet saved the entity.

Comment: The exact scenario you're speaking of is exactly what I'm trying to do, but it did not work. The navigation property remained null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this: (EF 4.1)

```
//Has to exists a record on Bob table with Id = 1
var thing = new Thing() { BobId = 1 };

var context = new YouContext();
context.Entry(thing ).State = EntityState.Unchanged;
context.Entry(thing ).Reference(x => x.Bob).Load();
```

and then thing.Bob is != null

Comment: That's what I was thinking was going to be the only option. I was more hoping that there was a way to configure the context to check for null entity references with an Id being present, and loading the reference. Alas, it appears not. I'm marking you as the answer since this is the closest it'll be.